# g++ -Wuninitialized doesn't show a warning at std::min()

Tags: c++, g++, gcc-warning

I compiled the following code with `g++ -Wuninitialized` (g++ Version 7.5.0) and I didn't get any warning:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int a, b;

    b = std::min(a, 0);

}
```

As you can see, `std::min()` is called with the parameters `a` and `0`, but `a` isn't initialized at this point. This should give you a warning, but it doesn't.

If you replace `std::min()` with a custom function, the compiler will give you a warning:

**Code**

```
int f(int x) {
  
    return 2 * x;

}

int main() {

    int a, b;

    b = f(a);

}
```

**Warning**

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:11:10: warning: 'a' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   11 |     b = f(a);
      |         ~^~~
```

Why does this not work with `std::min()`? I also tried `std::max()` and it also didn't give me a warning. But with `std::hypot()` I get one. Is there a way to make it also work for `std::min()`?

Comment: Please add the information about which compiler version you're running. Just paste the results of `g++ --version`.

Comment: Apples to oranges. Change the function to `int f(int const& x)` (like how `std::min` is implemented), and the warning goes away.  The `-Wuninitialized` is not guaranteed to be able to do a static analysis of all use cases of uninitialized variables.  It only catches the easy ones.

Comment: FWIW, latest `clang` [does issue a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/r65hYf).

Comment: @cigien g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Thanks, but always add all relevant information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @eljay Is there a compiler flag that would produce a warning in this case?

Comment: You should report a [bug to GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). FWIW, GCC 10.2 on Ubuntu20.04/x86-64 gives with `g++-10 -Wall -Wextra -c /tmp/tc14.cc -o /dev/null` a warning: `tc14.cc:5:12: warning: variable ‘b’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`

Comment: In these cases, I *do* get a warning when I used `-Wuninitialized-const-reference` flag, but I'm using **clang version 11.0.0**.

Comment: Appears to be [fixed in trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/z91979). `<source>:7:22: warning: 'a' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    7 |     b = std::min(a, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `std::min` takes its arguments by reference, and so at the call site GCC did not see a "read" from the uninitialized variable. For some reason, it doesn't even notice the uninitialized read when the function is optimized and inlined.

If you change your custom function to be `int f(const int& x)` then there's no warning for that either.

This seems to have been fixed for GCC 11 by the fixes for [Bug 10138](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10138). GCC now warns if you pass an uninitialized variable to a function that takes a `const T&` or a `const T*`, which makes sense because such a function almost certainly plans to read the variable, not write to it (which would require a cast). If it plans to read it, then it needs to be initialized, so the compiler warns now.